# How to fill the region between a circle and 2 lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I want to draw a picture like this, shade the shading region.

but the 2 lines are not closed paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle(3);
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (4,-1)--(4,1) node[pos=.5,right] () {\bfseries \large $z$};
        \clip (0,0) circle(3);
        \fill[red,draw,dashed] (-2,-3.5) rectangle (2,3.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: If You want a pattern, use, for example, this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle(3);
        \draw[->,line width=2pt] (4,-1)--(4,1) node[pos=.5,right] () {\bfseries \large $z$};
        \clip (0,0) circle(3);
        \fill[pattern=north east lines,draw,dashed] (-2,-3.5) rectangle (2,3.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You have this output:

[image]

Comment: Can the spacing between `north east lines` be increased?

Comment: We can use `patterns.meta` and configure `\draw [pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance=10pt],pattern color=red}] (x1,y1) rectangle (x2,y2);` [ref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571014/diagonal-tikz-patterns)